# Windows 10 Pro is Not booting - Bad System Config Info - Stopcode

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My HP Probook is not booting. It is stuck at the BSOD with message regarding 'BAD SYSTEM CONFIG INFO' windows.com/stopcode.

I have tried following option which did **not** resolve the issue:

- all options of recovery: Resetting without 'keep files' option, system restore, uninstalling last installed updates, . I got the error 'there was some error'.
- Using a bootable USB for Windows 10 March update (got from Microsoft site),  used all fixing options of `bootrec` in the command prompt tool. The commands were executed successfully.  [help article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-bad-system-config-info-error-windows10/)
- Tried booting into Safemode, but it just remains stuck at the Windows loading Splash screen

Not a Hardisk Issue: I have tried booting via Ubuntu Bootable USB, and have being able to get Read-write access to my Windows Partition. So, there seems to be no issue in Harddisk.

Is there any way to fix this? Also, the OS (Win7 Pro) came preinstalled (had consequently upgraded to Windows 10 pro via Windows Update) & do not have any recovery disks.

**Update (15/11/19)**: When no options worked(had also created [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-pro-is-not-booting-bad-system-config/8cbaf277-e2d0-4585-8028-22298051182c?tm=1573796801913) on Microsoft Support forum as well as had contact them via Chat), I had to finally resort to re-installing Windows 10 Pro using the installation media available on Microsoft site.
[My Reinstallation thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/finding-serial-key-for-reinstalling-windows-10-pro/438c5dd1-441f-455c-b2cc-db23c36d872b)

Comment: Did you try to boot in Safe Mode to see if the issue is still present? It may be a faulty hardware/bad driver. You can also try fixing the [BCD file](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-bad-system-config-info-error-windows10/).

Comment: We would hand the Quick Response Code to [a _MicroSoft_ Support Engineer](https://support.microsoft.com/) and let them know about the Software Fault.

Comment: Since you already used Reset, which removes all installed programs, copy your user files contained within `%UserProfile` (i.e. `C:\Users\<username>`) to external media and reinstall Windows 10 by downloading the [ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Microsoft.  While you can certainly troubleshoot and fix the error, it's more efficient [quicker] to reinstall due to using Reset.

Comment: @CaldeiraG While executing bootrec commands, had referred that same article. I didnt add the link earlier, as I wasnt sure if its allowed here. BCD fix commands executed successfully. But, issue not resolved.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Will add support query on Microsoft forum today, I'm unsure if I'll get any help there. My first goto is Stackexchange.

Comment: @JW0914 I have used the reset option, but it did not work. It gave 'there was some error'.I already of backup of data I need. Will the fresh installation process autodetect my serial key from existing Windows installation?

Comment: Win 10 licenses are attached to the motherboard's hardware ID and Microsoft account, so if you've already activated Win 10, when you reinstall, click _Skip_ when the installer asks for the product key.  Once you run Windows Update, the system will auto-activate.  Please note, you will need to install CPU related drivers _(chipset, IMEI, etc. pulled from the manufacturer's driver download page)_ prior to installing any software, Windows Updates, or other drivers.  Once the CPU related drivers are installed, rebooting after each install, then you can run Windows Update, and reinstall software.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai Had added support query on Microsoft site yesterday, so far no response

Comment: @JW0914 Will this also apply to Win 7 Pro? As originally, it was Win 7pro and consequently upgraded to Win 10 pro via Windows Update

Comment: @Shailesh AFAIK, only Win10 licenses are backed up to the user's Microsoft account.